# Vandermonde python3 matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a code to compute the vandermonde matrix but I can't get it to print in matrix form. Would really appreciate the help. my code is attached below.

```
x = [0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00]
col = 10
row = 10
matrix = [[0 for x in range(col)]for y in range(row)]
for i in (range(row)):
    matrix[i][0] = 1;
for i in (range(row)):
    for j in (1,2,3):
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j-1] * x[i]
for i in (range(row)):
    for j in (range(col)):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = "")
        A = ("\n")
    print(A)
```